# Mongodb localhost:27017 replica set switched to secondary localhost:27027

Tags: mongodb, localhost, replication

I'm fairly new to mongodb, just a couple of months.  I just converted my mongodb database to support a secondary replica set so I can watch collections.  I only added one secondary which I'm guessing now may not be the best after reading you should create an odd number, but it is a localhost on one machine.  I went through the instructions, got replication working fine for for half a day running my programs.  But for some reason recently it has switched the database for port 27017 from primary to secondary.  Primary was previously on localhost:27017 and secondary was on localhost:27027.  Now my normal program can't connect to localhost:27017 without an error, which I believe it is because it is a secondary replica set now when it was primary before, assuming you can only connect to a primary.   Here is the error msg.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mongodb.MongoNotPrimaryException: Command failed with error 10107 (NotWritablePrimary): 'not master' on server localhost:27017.
```

1. I'm perplexed why mongodb switched the replica set primary in the first place.  I doubt an error occurred, but certainly possible, but I haven't had a single "localhost" error in months of development.
2. For now, ideally how would I switch 27017 back to be the primary.  How do I do that so my existing programs can function again?
3. Eventually when in production, what is the best methodology to handle this, assuming a lookup to a DNS entry to an ip address and suddenly the primary gets changed because of a fail over?
4. Given question 3 is a bit more involved, is there something I can do in my development environment to better simulate a production environment.

I use StackOverflow extensively but this is my first post so thanks for anyone who can provide advice.

Answer (score 1):

1. Without knowing more about the replica configuration and circumstances of the switch over I'm not sure anyone could confidently answer question 1 but it may not be important compared to question 3.
2. When you want to manually switch the primary you can manipulate the priority settings:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/

Or run manual commands to freeze or step down the current primary:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary/#force-a-member-to-be-primary-using-database-commands

3. The safest option is to ensure your application is aware of all replicas in the replica set. Then when you have these situations where something unexpected has happened the application will fail over to a writable db without any issues.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/#connect-to-a-replica-set

4. I can only suggest setting up some VMs or containers as replica set members to better represent a production environment.

https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo

Comment: I can't upvote because I'm nube.  But thanks for answer #2 and #3

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using the connect string which comprised both replica sets, which I was unaware I needed to do.  Such as for java:

```
mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost:27017,localhost:27027");
```

This also worked for Mongo Compass so I was able to connect to the secondary database.  I didn't know you needed to provide paths to all replica sets when trying to connect, but in retrospect makes goods sense if something is down.

Comment: This depends on the driver and there are multiple ways to obtain a replica set connection. See e.g. https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/create-client/#replica-set-connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a replica set for testing, you can create a single-node RS. Follow the instructions for creating a RS but only add one node.